# Find Orphaned Pages in WP

Tags: wordpress

I am working on a WP site with a number of pages in the sitemap I've generated but I'm pretty sure that a lot of them are orphaned (bar the sitemap itself).

Is there a way I can tally up internal links and see if there are pages without any (I'd also be keen to know what those links are for pages with very few links).

Comment: Screaming Frog http://www.screamingfrog.co.uk/seo-spider/ can be used up to 500 pages without a licence and SEO Powersuite http://www.link-assistant.com/ will spider your entire site and return 2/3rds of the results without a licence. Both can help you audit your site. Screaming Frog is a $99 per year license and SEO Powersuite is a $200 one time license for individuals (New- previously you had to pay the $700 fee). For the long run SEO Powersuite is a better bargain for the long run and can audit your site well, however, Screaming Frog is purely for auditing the site and simpler over all.

Comment: You will very likely get an answer on http://wordpress.stackexchange.com.